# Should I use tags for cities?

Tags: entries, tags

I would like to have some advise on the following:

I'll be running a site with events. These events (channel entries) will take place in a certain city. I don't want to setup every city as a category, but use tags instead. My questions are:

1. Is it logical to use tags for cities?
2. Can I list all events based on a city (tag) on my template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably and yes.

**Using tags for cities:**

If you want to allow users to add any city they want, tags are perfect. If not, you should predefine them, and use categories, dropdowns or multi-selects.

Since you don't know if the user has actually entered a city, you should consider validating it with a custom plugin:

- Wait for the [entries.onBeforeSaveEntry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onBeforeSaveEntry) event
- Check if the entered tag is a city. (You could use the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=de))

.

**List entries which have a specific tag:**

You can use [relations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations) to find all entries which have a specific tag:

```twig
{% set tag = craft.tags.name('miami') %}
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(tag) %}

{# Gets all entries which have the 'miami' tag #}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Victor, but if you're looking to loop through all the cities (regardless of how many you have) and show entries related to them I'd do it like this:

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').limit(null) %}
{% for tag in craft.tags('cities') %}
    <h2>{{ tag }}</h2>
        {% for entry in entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
            {# entry #}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an address plugin available, that might be useful for your event locations. It's called [craft-smartmap](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-smartmap/wiki) by Lindsey D.

Addresses are auto-completed on input, latitude and longitude are calculated (for maps output etc.) and you have access to the cities names like with any other field type.

I don't know if it's overkill for your goals and you just need the city names. Nevertheless added this here as it might be worth a look.

Comment: Seconded. Incredible plugin and I believe he has some great features coming down the pipeline for it very soon :)